# SQL pivot attachments

Tags: sql

can anybody help me with pivot command, i have select:

```
select 
RegistrationNumber as [reg.nr.],
  RegistrationDate as [reg.data],
  DocumentTitle as [antraštė],
  a.FileName as [attachment]
  from
  Documents d
  left join DocumentsPreparedUser p 
  on d.DocumentId = p.DocumentId
  inner join dba.crm_SystemUser sup
  on p.SystemUserId = sup.SystemUserId
  left join dba.crm_SystemUser supas
  on d.EmployeeSignerId = supas.SystemUserId
  inner join dba.doc_Attachments a
  on a.DocumentId = d.DocumentId
```

and i need result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aObtm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community. I would use your query as a `CTE` to extract that view. After that a pivot could be applied to get a result close to the one you desire. As far as you know the different `Attachment`, you can use `COUNT` in the `PIVOT` and you could get the occurrences on those users. You can review this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4ca43e47716b4704691b5781e32abad7)

```
    WITH your_table(RegNr, RegDate, DocumentTitle, UserName,Attachment) AS (
      enter your query
    )
    SELECT  RegNr, RegDate, DocumentTitle, UserName, [AttachmentName1], [AttachmentName2], [AttachmentName3], [AttachmentName4]  
    FROM  
    (SELECT *   
        FROM your_table) AS SourceTable  
    PIVOT  
    (  
    COUNT(Attachment)  
    FOR Attachment IN ([AttachmentName1], [AttachmentName2], [AttachmentName3], [AttachmentName4])  
    ) AS PivotTable;
```